# Error handling in Spring Kafka with properties file?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm getting a bunch of deserialization failure before my `Kafka Listener` is hit. I was looking into the things Gary Russel built, but having issues getting it to work. All my stuff is configured via properties file.

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

So if I add these, my understanding is it wraps an error in the headers of the consumer record? My ultimate goal is to have any deserialization exception hit some custom class I have so I can handle what I want to do with it. IE, forward to my dead letter handler which uploads failed data to s3.

I tried adding the errorhandler flag to the kafkalistener, but that also didn't do anything.

## Updated Property Configuration

I've updated my configuration, it's still unclear to me if this is correct. It's not working, so I assume not.

None of the custom code is getting called

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.value.deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.key.deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.function=com.thing.cyclic.service.FailedFooProvider

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.specific.avro.reader=true
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.auto.register.schemas=false
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level=read_committed
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual_immediate
```

## BadFoo

```
public class BadFoo {

    private final FailedDeserializationInfo failedDeserializationInfo;

    public BadFoo(FailedDeserializationInfo failedDeserializationInfo) {
        this.failedDeserializationInfo = failedDeserializationInfo;
    }

    public FailedDeserializationInfo getFailedDeserializationInfo() {
        return this.failedDeserializationInfo;
    }
}
```

## FailedFooProvider

```
public class FailedFooProvider implements Function<FailedDeserializationInfo, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(FailedDeserializationInfo info) {
        System.out.println("");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling).

Also take a look at the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` code, which can used to publish the failed record to an other topic. You can model your code after that to obtain the header(s) containing the failed `byte[]`.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/fa5c35e9b15c4cecfc6ea2bbbf9e7745bc5d9f75/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java#L169-L178

The recoverer is used in conjunction with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

Configure the error handler as a `@Bean` and Spring Boot will automatically wire it into the container.

Comment: Is value function deprecated? I've reviewed the code and docs, but it's still unclear to me how I should go about this. I've updated the original question with my configuration. Does that look correct? I'm still confused on how I specify the class I own that grabs the failed record

Comment: currently on 2.2.8

Comment: `>Is value function deprecated?` I don't know what that means; what "value function"? Declare a `@Bean` of type `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` - e.g. `public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> recoverer)` - call your code from the `BiConsumer`. e.g.  `(rec, ex) -> {...}`. 2.2 is no longer supported; you should update to at least 2.3. The code in the recoverer I pointed you to was not introduced until 2.3; I don't recall how much of this was available in 2.2.x.